# Count of element using Xquery

Tags: xquery

I need to extract the count of that element which has the maximum occurrences, For example in below xml, I need count to be returned as 2 which is for the Email element.

```
<root>
   <_1>
      <attributes>
         <Email>
            <ov>true</ov>
            <value>
               <Email>
                  <ov>true</ov>
                 <value>abc@hghh.gff</value>
               </Email>
            </value>
         </Email>
         <Email>
            <ov>true</ov>
            <value>
               <Email>
                  <ov>true</ov>
                  <value>xyn@qwe.com</value>
               </Email>
            </value>
         </Email>
         <UniqueId>
            <ov>true</ov>
            <value>39919741</value>
         </UniqueId>
      </attributes>
   </_1>
</root>
```

Comment: Please help with a generic approach, as there can be 100 of element in source XML

Comment: I see four `Email` elements,although two of them are nested. There are five `ov` elements. So you will need to explain more precisely what you want to achieve or what you consider a "maximum occurrence".

Comment: We can ignore further child attributes of the element, so I want to consider elements "Email" ,"UniqueId " and based on them, need to evaluate the count

Answer (score 1):

Well, select the elements you are interested in, group them by the `node-name()`, order by the `count` of the grouped elements and take the first in descending sort order or last in ascending sort order e.g.

```
for $element in outermost((//Email, //UniqueId))
group by $name := node-name($element)
order by count($element) descending
count $pos
where $pos = 1
return $name || ' : ' || count($element)
```

when run on your sample outputs `Email : 2`.

Example at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e2c

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the `eg:highest()` higher order function found in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#highest-lowest, and then apply it to the selected set of nodes $E as follows:

```
let $E := (:the selected elements:)
return eg:highest(distinct-values($E!node-name()), 
                  function($n){count($E[node-name() eq $n])})
```

The `eg:highest($seq, $f)` function is a generic higher-order function that finds the items in `$seq` having the highest value for the supplied function `$f`.